# In Android, how do you create a virtually gallery folder like Facebook and Picasa web albums do?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm an experienced programmer, but not so much in the Android world though, so I'm hoping someone experienced can give me a starting point.

I'm looking to integrate with the Gallery in Android. I noticed Picasa Web Albums and Facebook both dynamically integrate with your gallery in recent versions of Android. The photos aren't actually stored on your phone, but the phone treats them like they are with a small icon in the bottom left that represents the service.

Can anyone give me a starting point as to what in the SDK provides this service? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing, however you can get an online image and integrate in a ImageView without the need to download it.

Comment: Those are cache images. You can also implement such feature in your application just by creating some LRU cache classes and set adapter with gallery and image views.

Comment: Hey Chintan, I'm not sure I'm 100% following what you are saying. Let me explain it better: If I go to "Albums" in Gallery, it shows all of my Facebook albums, as well as the "Camera" album of local photos. The Facebook albums have a small Facebook icon in the bottom left. If I select it, it shows all the photos in that Facebook album. I can then tap on a photo and it displays a hi-res version. They aren't just cached thumbnails... it is fully integrated and acts like the images are local to the phone. I can look at my entire Facebook photo library virtually. There has to be a way to do this.